# How to un-nest nested lists in php

Tags: php, list, split, domdocument, explode

I have a nested unordered list like this (simplified version / the depth is variable) :

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Root</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Page A</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#" title="Page A1">Page 1 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Using PHP, is there a nice way to "explode" this nested list in (for this example) 3 lists ?

Thanks for your help

Edit :

The expected output will be :

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Root</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Page A</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="Page A1">Page 1 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: I think that's a pretty complicated manipulation no matter what approach you use, but a good start would be loading your document into http://php.net/dom and then extracting your ul elements with an xpath query for '//ul'.  You'd then have to do some additional work to strip any child ul elements from the returned results, move the recovered nodes into new documents, and serialize them back to markup.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$lists = '<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Root</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page A</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="#" title="Page A1">Page 1 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>';

$list_array = explode('<ul>', $lists);
foreach($list_array as $list){
    // Now you have a single list, but missing the <ul>
    // at the start. replace that and assign to a variable or whatever.
}
```

Comment: That won't produce the desired output -- the first two results will have no closing tags, and the 3rd will have 3 sets of closing tags.

Comment: Yes, and there's something else : if each list has multiple items it won't work

Comment: Quite right. Coffee was still brewing ... I need to be patient and wait to drink some in the morning.